# Create multiple PDFs from links

Tags: pdf, websites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recursive HTML to PDF](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88047/recursive-html-to-pdf)

There is a software or a script that given some links will return pdf version of it?