# Recursive HTML to PDF

Tags: pdf, html

I have a folder with this structure:

```
/main-folder
 /index.html
 /subfolder1
    /index1.html
    /file1.html
```

with many sub folder and only html files... i want to convert all them to pdf using only one command or a simple script that doesn't require all file names.

Do you know one

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest installing the WKHtmlToPDF tool from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ (moved from: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

You can then change to the root folder and use find and xargs to convert them:

```
cd /main-folder
find . -name \*.html | sed 's/.html$//g' | xargs -n 1 --replace=X wkhtmltopdf X.html X.pdf
```

This will then build a PDF with each HTML file.

Comment: i solved with alist of files and a bash for but this is a lot better!

Answer (score 5):

The following command should do the job for one link:

```
gnome-web-print http://www.ubuntu.com ubuntu.pdf
```

For multiple links, it shouldn't be difficult to write a loop that handles each link one by one.